# Displaying data points and concatenating plots into one file

Tags: matlab, plot, scilab

Hi I have a couple of Scilab questions which I'm hoping someone will be able to answer.

Firstly, I need to display certain data points on my graph which is part of a different loop. Is there an simple way to do so?  maybe something like

```
xstring(x,y,[value of x], [value of y])?
```

when I do this, it always displays the whole x and y matrix instead of just the value at that one point

Secondly, I have separate files that I would like to concatenate into 1 pdf file? I am not sure how to do this.

```
z = 1:3

scf(z)
plot(x,Y)

xs2pdf(z,filename)?
```

I've tried this but I always only get the last image saved into the pdf.

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Display data points

```
// Some function
x = 1:10;
y = x^2;

plot(x,y);

//Display fifth number
i = 5;

// Create a nice string label
stringToDisplay = sprintf("X: %d, Y: %d", x(i), y(i));

// Put it at the correct spot on the plot
xstring( x(i), y(i), stringToDisplay );
```

The nicest thing would to place it in a function:

```
function plotMyLabel(i)
    stringToDisplay = sprintf("X: %d, Y: %d", x(i), y(i));
    xstring( x(i), y(i), stringToDisplay );
endfunction
```

### Multiple plots

You could create a figure with multiple subplots and export it. See [subplot](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/en_US/subplot.html) documentation of scilab.

```
//plot first graph
subplot(1,2,1);

plot(x1,y1);

//plot second graph 
subplot(1,2,2);

plot(x2,y2);

// Format the figure at will
fig = gcf();

fig.figure_size=[1200, 800];
fig.children.margins = [0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05];

//export to file
xs2pdf(fig, 'my_out_file');
```

Comment: I did try subplot but the issue I'm having is that I have too many data points and using subplots makes the graph impossible to see. Which is why I decided to just use one plot per window. Is there a way to join different window plots into one pdf?

Comment: You can format your plots any which way you like see [axes_properties](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.0/en_US/axes_properties.html). You can also make the figure bigger. See my updated answer.